# SQL compare 2 unmatched values

Tags: sql, compare

I have two tables i.e tableA and tableB. I need to fetch 3 column values from these tables(name,date and type). name and date from tableA and type from tableB.
To get a type from tableB I have to match the name from tableA with name from tableB value.

```
Query:
select distinct a.name, a.time, b.type from tableA a,tableB b where a.name=b.name 

tableA:
name,date
harish,2020-07-11
Test1 - Point,2020-08-11
Test1 - Logic,2020-08-11
Test2 - Collect,2020-08-10

tableB:
name,type
harish,AB
Test1,OC
Test2,CD

select distinct a.name, a.time, b.type from tableA a, tableB b
where
((a.name='Test1'+' '+'-'+' '+'Point' or a.name='Test1'+' '+'-'+' '+'Logic') = b.name)
and b.type = 'OC' and a.name LIKE 'Test1'
```

Can anybody help me how to match two table column values when we dont have exact matchning names?

Comment: We can, if you're specific about how you want such a match to succeed?

Comment: `'Test1'+' '+'-'+' '+'Logic'` is identical to `'Test1 - Logic'`, but look how much easier it is to read the second form than the first... Don't stop and start string constant concatenation; it makes the code a mess

Comment: `from tableA a,tableB b` - it's been possible (and strongly recommended) to avoid doing joins like this for about 30 years now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess at how you want to match them:

```
select a.name, a.time, b.type 
from 
  tableA a
  INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.name LIKE CONCAT(b.name, '%')
```

LIKE doesn't care how it comes to be that the operand on the right contains its wildcards - it could be in a column value itself, in a string constant (the usual way) or concatenated on. Ultimately, it looks like you want `Test1 - Logic` on the left to match with `Test1` on the right, so we need to make the right match pattern into `Test1%`

Note: Using `CONCAT` means that if `b.name` is a `NULL`, then it will match with everything, because the result of the CONCAT operation is `'%'`. If you want it to match nothing if the `b.name` is NULL, it's probably safest(most cros-db-compatible) to put a condition in that excludes NULL b's but if this is SQLServer then you can use `+` to do the concat instead; `NULL + 'anything'` results in NULL in SQLserver, and nothing is LIKE NULL

Comment: Thanks Caius for your time, it worked. But can we change the name from a.name to b.name once condition satisfies? I want to display data like Test1,2020-08-11,OC

Comment: Sure can, just change what is after the `SELECT` to `b.name` instead of `a.name`. I only used a.name because you did...